# Split string in stringbuilder

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I have a text file which is located on my server.

Contents of the text file are like this one

```
hello,200
james,300
robin,100
```

And this is what I coded until now and tested for iterate each item in stringbuilder but it does not iterate each item. I can't understand where is the problem.

Any help much appreciated

```
WinHttp.Open("GET", "http://mytmmt.cafe24.com/test.txt")
WinHttp.Send()
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb.Append(WinHttp.ResponseText)   
Dim lines() As String = Split(sb.ToString, vbNewLine)
For Each line As String In lines
    Debug.Print(line) '<---------here should have to print but this line skip
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [StringRerader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StringReader(v=vs.110).aspx) will make the reading of your text more controlled, and it will resolve your problem:

```
WinHttp.Open("GET", "http://mytmmt.cafe24.com/test.txt")
WinHttp.Send()
Using sr As IO.StringReader = New IO.StringReader(WinHttp.ResponseText)
    Do
        line = sr.ReadLine
        'Do something with "line"
    Loop Until String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see the result of the link "http://mytmmt.cafe24.com/test.txt", it is wrapping with white space but not with new line. Split with space like below.

```
WinHttp.Open("GET", "http://mytmmt.cafe24.com/test.txt")
WinHttp.Send()
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb.Append(WinHttp.ResponseText)   
Dim lines() As String = Split(sb.ToString, " ")
For Each line As String In lines
    Debug.Print(line) '<---------here should have to print but this line skip
Next
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! i tested but it also skip debug.print(line). i really don't understand where is problem.

Comment: replace with "Chr(10)"(Line Feed) like below. Dim sep As Char = Chr(10)
        Dim lines() As String = result.ToString.Split(sep)
        Console.WriteLine(lines.Length)
        For Each line As String In lines
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Next